# Extract certain dataframes of lists of dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe, extract

I have a list of dataframes. Each is build up as followed:
[image: Dataframe]

No i want to extract the dataframes beginning at a certain time.

```
Collection=[]
for i in range(len(subdfs)):
   if any(subdfs[i]['Zeitpunkt'][subdfs[i]['Zeitpunkt'].dt.hour.eq(12)]):
      Collection.append(subdfs[i]['Zeitpunkt'])
```

With this code i am able to extract every dataframe where the hour 12 appears. But i only want the dataframes where the hour 12 is in the **first** row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Collection = [subdf for subdf in subdfs if subdf.iloc[0, subdf.columns.get_loc('Zeitpunkt')].hour == 12]
```

Comment: Doesn't work.
KeyError: 0

Comment: Yes, it also works with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It worked with:

```
Collection = [subdfs for subdfs in subdfs if subdfs.iloc[0, 1].hour == 12]
```